# Stack Layout layout nightmare with Xamarin XAML forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following code:

```
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,10,0,10" BackgroundColor="Green" Padding="5,5,5,5">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="Blue">
              <Label Text="SHOW COMPLETED TASKS" BackgroundColor="Red" Style="{StaticResource lblSubHeading_Black}" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Switch x:Name="CompletedJobsSwitch" Toggled="CompletedJobsSwitch_Toggled" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" IsToggled="{Binding isOn}" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
  </StackLayout>
```

It all loads fine but when the app loads it is showing, but the Switch is not flush right. Why? It's really annoying, seems really inconsistent[image]
I've looked at http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21226/how-to-right-align-a-view-inside-a-list-item but this doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not inconsistent. The `StackLayout` only takes as much space as needed. Try to put a `Grid` around it at the highest level.

Comment: when I say inconstant, i mean XAML for Xamarin forms, but ive set the StackLayout tto fill and expand, why isnt it doing that ? Adding a grid seems to be sticking a plaster over the issue.

Comment: You don't have to add a grid, just replace your top-level StackLayout with a Grid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Green">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Label Text="SHOW COMPLETED TASKS" BackgroundColor="Red" />
  <Switch x:Name="CompletedJobsSwitch" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This solution worked great for me too.  I was having very much the same problem with a StackLayout with Orientation="Horizontal" with the last item being a switch set with HorizontalOptions="End".  It was working fine (aligning the switch to the right on the screen) on all sizes of Android screens, and wider IOS screens, but on smaller IOS screens the switch was sliding to the left as you've pictured.  The Grid approach above works fine on all screens I've tested.

Answer (score 4):

This is well-known issue with combination of `StackLayout` and `Label`:

- [Bugzilla #28650](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28650)
- [Bugzilla #31128](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31128)
- [Bugzilla #33841](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33841)

You could use workaround described by [JamesMontemagno](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/152969/#Comment_152969). The point is to use `Grid` instead of `StackLayout` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm just too late to the party and some bugs have been fixed, but for others that arrive here through searching:

For the lefthand item use HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
For the right align item use HorizontalOptions="End"
The switch is a fixed length component, so you don't want to use expand.If you do use EndAndExpand, it will add some padding to the right, ruining your right alignment.
The label wants to fill the remaining space, so tell it to expand.

```
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,10" BackgroundColor="Green" Padding="5,5,5,5">
            <Label Text="SHOW COMPLETED TASKS" BackgroundColor="Red"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
            <Switch x:Name="CompletedJobsSwitch"  HorizontalOptions="End" IsToggled="false" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
</StackLayout>
```